# Tensorflow: ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using the `tf.data.Dataset` API and have a dataset that's ~500K rows and ~1,800 columns.  When I try:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"reviews": data}, labels))
```

I get back:

```
ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.
```

I've googled around and seen a lot of people run into this issue but no satisfactory answers.  Is there a way to get around this limit or a tensorflow approach that will break up my `dataset`?  I already batch it but that happens after calling:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"reviews": data}, labels))
```

For what it's worth, my code to read the data from CSV into a `tf.data.Dataset` works when I use 10% of the data.

Any suggestions would be awesome!

Comment: What datatype are u using to store this data?

Comment: @Smokrow The numpy arrays I build from have dtype `np.int32`

Comment: Ah. Sry I meant shape.

Comment: @Smokrow `(500000, 2000)`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your dataset you could try using the tf [dataset api](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data)This means you could try converting your dataset into a tfrecord or you could try [csv](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data) files. The datasetapi takes care of loading your data in the background while you are training other data. This speeds up the training process significantly as well